# Extracting text from an xml file

Tags: xml

If I have an xml file containing entries like this

```
<root>
  <d:entry d:title="OYSTER">
    <span class="foot">
      <span role="text">
      foo</span>
    </span>
    <span class="sg">
      <span id="004">
    <span role="text">
      <span class="pos">
        <span class="baz">tart</span>
        <d:pos></d:pos>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span id="005" class="star">
      <span class="NAME">GUYBRUSH THREEPWOOD
      <d:def></d:def></span>
      <span role="text" class="bar">:</span>
      <span role="text" class="grog">
        <span class="ex">pirate
        </span>
        <span class="parrot">.</span>
      </span>
    </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </d:entry>
</root>
```

how can I extract the text 'GUYBRUSH THREEPWOOD' by supplying the (d:)title
'OYSTER' and the class 'NAME'?

Comment: The best way is to use an HTML parser but first, add the expected output to your question. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: Is that the actual XML? There is a namespace, `d`, that you haven't declared.

Answer (score 2):

Using `xq` (part of `yq`, a `jq`-like parser collection for YAML, XML, and TOML, from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), because `xmlstarlet` is too strict about your missing namespace declaration (see end of question for an `xmlstarlet` solution anyway).

```bsh
xq -r --arg title "OYSTER" --arg class "NAME" '
    (.. | select(."@d:title"? == $title)) |
    (.. | select(."@class"?   == $class))."#text"' file.xml
```

This recursively selects any document node that has a `d:title` attribute (the initial `@` used in the expression denotes a node's attribute rather than a node's name) that has the value `OYSTER`.

Given these nodes (only one in the example), they are searched recursively for any node that has a `class` attribute with value `NAME`.

For each such node, the node's value is extracted.

The two strings `OYSTER` and `NAME` are tied to internal variables on the command line with the `--arg` option.

The output, given the document in the question:

```
GUYBRUSH THREEPWOOD
```

If other nodes than `d:entry` can have a `d:title` attribute, and/or other nodes than `span` can have a `class` attribute and you want to avoid matching these attributes in the wrong type of node, then make sure that you only look in the appropriate nodes:

```bsh
xq -r --arg title "OYSTER" --arg class "NAME" '
    (.. | ."d:entry"? | select(."@d:title"? == $title)) |
    (.. | .span?[]?   | select(."@class"?   == $class))."#text"' file.xml
```

---

As a reference, since `xq` is actually calling `jq` with a JSON document behind the scenes, the following is the JSON document that your XML document is translated into:

```json
{
  "root": {
    "d:entry": {
      "@d:title": "OYSTER",
      "span": [
        {
          "@class": "foot",
          "span": {
            "@role": "text",
            "#text": "foo"
          }
        },
        {
          "@class": "sg",
          "span": {
            "@id": "004",
            "span": [
              {
                "@role": "text",
                "span": {
                  "@class": "pos",
                  "span": {
                    "@class": "baz",
                    "#text": "tart"
                  },
                  "d:pos": null
                }
              },
              {
                "@id": "005",
                "@class": "star",
                "span": [
                  {
                    "@class": "NAME",
                    "d:def": null,
                    "#text": "GUYBRUSH THREEPWOOD"
                  },
                  {
                    "@role": "text",
                    "@class": "bar",
                    "#text": ":"
                  },
                  {
                    "@role": "text",
                    "@class": "grog",
                    "span": [
                      {
                        "@class": "ex",
                        "#text": "pirate"
                      },
                      {
                        "@class": "parrot",
                        "#text": "."
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Assuming the document has a proper declaration of the `d` namespace, `xmlstarlet` may be used to extract the wanted text like so:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -m '//d:entry[@d:title = "OYSTER"]' \
    -v '//span[@class = "NAME"]' -nl file.xml
```

Or, with internal variables set on the command line with `--var` (note the inclusion of the quotation in the values),

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t --var title='"OYSTER"' --var class='"NAME"' \
    -m '//d:entry[@d:title = $title]' \
    -v '//span[@class = $class]' -nl file
```

Both of these start with matching any `d:entry` node whose `d:title` attribute is `OYSTER`.  For each such matching node, it recursively looks for `span` nodes with a `class` attribute with value `NAME`.  The value of each such node is outputted.

Comment: thank you.  would it be an alternative to add a declaration?  (i'm 100% ignorant about xml.)

Comment: @humbug I'm assuming that your actual XML file has a root element saying something like `<root xmlns:d="http://some.url.here">`, right?

Comment: yeah, sorry, i didn't realize that was significant

Comment: @humbug You may want to update the XML in your question.